# Set label.text over AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have `ViewController` and from some reasons I must set label.text from AppDelegate.m
How can I do that?

I've tryed with this code but with no success:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    home.dateCreatedLabel.text = @"date createdddd";
}
```

The reason why I must put this in AppDelegate is because I'm getting JSON from website and I must do that also in `applicationWillEnterForeground:` to check every time for update and I solved updating Core Data but no how to change label.text.

Or can I some how force `HomeViewController` to refresh?

Comment: not required as it is self explained

Comment: I can't imagine the reason for setting a label from AppDelegate. Could you detail why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in response to some of the other answers, it's actually not a terrible idea to expose certain UI components in the public interface to your view or view controller.

For example, Apple started doing this with table view cells by directly exposing the labels and views because it's just easier and more flexible for developers. So they now have a property for `textLabel` whereas previously they had only had a `setText:` method. This means you can now set the label text, as well as customize any other thing you need to on the label itself.

In your case, you can expose the label as a standard property on your view controller and then access that from the app delegate. But before you access it, you need to make sure the view controller's view has been loaded otherwise the label property will return nil. You can force the view to load by just querying the `-view` method on the controller:

```
// force view to load
[viewController view];
// and now access the label
viewController.label.text = @"whatever";
```

If you need to figure out how to get a reference/pointer to the view controller from the app delegate, you should be able to dive into the properties on your root view controller, or use delegation so the app delegate can implement a delegate interface to provide the text for the label.

**EDIT:**

In response to your update with example code, it definitely looks like you need to do this before accessing the label:

```
// force view to load
[home view];
home.dateCreatedLabel.text = @"date createdddd";
```

One word of warning though: if your view controller is unloaded due to a memory warning, the text you have set previously will be lost.

It's would be a better idea to set the date on the view controller using an `NSDate` property, and get the view controller to set the label's text when the property changes, and also in `-viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score -1):

just create one property for that in viewController's .h file and in appdelegate.m

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

in this method at the time of initialization of viewController assign the property.